# How to make a .sh script run before each test in Meson

Tags: meson-build

I have a number of tests in my meson.build file. Each one of these tests needs to run the same .sh file but with a different parameter before the test is run. This is because my .sh file creates a server on the specified port, and each test needs a different port. I would like for all of this to happen when I execute `meson test`.
`add_test_setup` doesn't seem to work because it adds the same setup to every test. `run_command` doesn't seem to work because it doesn't seem like it will run when I run `meson test`.
With all that said, what can I add to my meson.build file to make each test run a .sh script beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to call the script itself as part of your `test()` call, e.g.

```
script = find_program(...)
exe1 = ...
exe2 = ...
exe3 = ...

test('test-exe1', script, args: [exe1.full_path(), '--port=123'], depends: exe1)
test('test-exe2', script, args: [exe2.full_path(), '--port=456'], depends: exe2)
test('test-exe3', script, args: [exe3.full_path(), '--port=789'], depends: exe3)
```

In this case, your script would be responsible for

1. Creating the server, then
2. Running the provided test executable